# How do you resolve missing values in TFS Analysis Database?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Azure DevOps TFS Addin 2019 - Report Warnings

I recently migrated TFS 2017 to TFS 2018 (still in preprod environment for testing) and setup Reporting to point to TFS 2018 environment (Tfs_Warehouse and Tfs_Analysis). I’m running Windows 10 and Office 365 ProPlus. I installed Azure DevOps Integration Tool for Office 2019 and removed Team Foundation Server Office Integration 2017 because the “Team” addin was missing from Excel. Now that the “Team” addin/tab is back in Excel I go to “Team” - New Report - select the preprod environment - select defaultcollection - select Team Project - Connect - select a query and next - and receive the following warning:

> TF208064: A PivotTable and PivotChart report for the ‘Tags’ field will
> not be created. The field is not reportable. Click Finish to create
> the other reports, click Back to specify another query, or click Help
> for more information.
>
> TF208059: The filter that uses the ‘Team Project’ field uses values
> that will not be used in the PivotTable and PivotChart reports. These
> values are not present in Analysis Services database. Instead, the
> filter will include all values for that field. Click Finish to create
> the reports, click Back to specify another query, or click Help for
> more information.
>
> TF208059: The filter that uses the ‘Work Item Type’ field uses values
> that will not be used in the PivotTable and PivotChart reports. These
> values are not present in Analysis Services database. Instead, the
> filter will include all values for that field. Click Finish to create
> the reports, click Back to specify another query, or click Help for
> more information.
>
> TF208059: The filter that uses the ‘State’ field uses values that will
> not be used in the PivotTable and PivotChart reports. These values are
> not present in Analysis Services database. Instead, the filter will
> include all values for that field. Click Finish to create the reports,
> click Back to specify another query, or click Help for more
> information.

I have rebuilt DataWarehouse and Analysis server but same warnings.

How do I fix these warnings?

Comment: The error seems to come from the compatibility of Integration Tool for Office 2019 and TFS2018. How about the result when you use the Team Foundation Server Office Integration 2017 and try to check if this issue can be reproduced on other clients or machine?

Comment: I originally had Team Foundation Server Office Integration 2017 installed but the "Team" Addin was no where to be found after upgrading to Office 365.  The "Team" addin appeared in Excel after installing Azure DevOps Integration Tool for Office 2019.

Comment: I resolved TF208059 warnings by updating SetWarehouseJobEnabledState to enabled and running ProcessWarehouse.

However, I still get:

TF208064: A PivotTable and PivotChart report for the ‘Tags’ field will not be created. The field is not reportable. Click Finish to create the other reports, click Back to specify another query, or click Help for more information.

Comment: I attempted to update 'Tags' reference name Field: System.Tags reportingtype to dimension but received: You cannot change the reportable attributes of field System.Tags.  You can only define the reportable attributes for fields of the following data types: Integer, Double, String, or DateTime.

Command: witadmin changefield /collection:https://site/DefaultCollection /n:System.Tags /reportingtype:dimension

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/dd236909(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Any thoughts on fixing this warning?

Comment: Glad to know that resolved the TF208059 warnings. For the TF208064, what query you are using? If it have any custom field in it, or how about the result when you use another simple query?

Comment: Here is my query: 1. field - assigned to me, operator - =, value - me; 2. And - Field - State, operator - Does Not Contain, Value - Closed.